# Как разделить карту на заданное количество областей?

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр, генерация-случайных-данных

пишу игру Dice War, но застрял в самом начале - на генерации карты.

Необходимо игровое поле разделить на области, площадь которых будет одинаковой. Для поля 10х10 и 10 областей это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4
1 1 1 1 2 3 3 5 5 4
8 8 8 8 2 2 2 5 5 4
8 8 8 7 7 2 2 5 5 4
0 0 8 8 7 7 5 5 5 4
0 0 0 8 9 7 5 4 4 4
9 0 0 0 9 7 7 7 6 6
9 0 0 0 9 6 7 7 6 6
9 9 9 9 9 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Поле ограничено, или "непрерывно" – уйдя влево вверх оказываемся справа снизу? Т.е. продолжение поля «1» может быть снизу справа?

Comment: Поле будет именно отн. низкой размерности 10х10, или же в реальности там 1024х1024 рабочий вариант?

Comment: у области может быть отросток по диагонали, или обязательно, чтобы свой сосед был по вертикали или горизонтали?

Comment: @Sergiks, поле ограничено, длина стороны - 50 - 100 клеток, у клетки четыре соседа.

Comment: @Rennorb, у вас буква "л" сдупилась в заголовке.

Comment: Думаю, что стоит такой алгоритм попробовать:
1. Выбираем случайную точку.
2. От нее строим "змейку" путем выбора случайного направления, помечаем следующую точку нашей. 
3. Повторяем пункт 3 пока не наберем 10 клеточек. Если уткнулись - возврат назад на одну клетку (при этом только что покрашенную клетку сохраняем) и пробуем выбрать следующего соседа.
Далее повторяем.
В результате мы получим разделенные область с "дырками", которые никуда не относятся.Поэтому далее все равно придется применить алгоритм, который дырки скомпонует в одну область и приклеит к областям с недостающими клетками.

Comment: Рост областей не обязательно змейкой: отрасти может любая из клеток области. Можно её и направление роста выбирать случайно, и расставить приоритеты: заполнить мелкую дырку рядом важнее, чем выйти в открытое поле, где никого рядом нет.

Comment: @Rennorb напишите, если найдёте красивое решение, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать следующим образом. Сначала кидаем случайно центры областей с равномерным распределением, потом все элементы связываем с ближайшими центрами областей. В прошлом делал генератор текстур на этом алгоритме, получаются такие пазлы:

[image: Текстурка]

В конце нужно проверять площадь каждой области, переносить элементы из слишком больших в слишком маленькие. Если Вы всерьёз взялись за написание игры, то запрограммировать эти действия должно быть не сложно.

**Update.** Усреднять размеры областей можно разными времени написания и времени выполнения способами:

1. Глобальный подход. Ищем пары ближайших областей с избытком и недостатком клеток, переносим элементы между ними. Пример: `1 1 1 2 2 3` => `1 1 2 2 3 3`.
2. Методы тыка. Все области с площадью больше средней отдают клетки другим областям без переизбытка площади, а все со слишком малой площадью забирают клетки у областей без недостатка. Затратно по времени, но если карты генерируются редко, то может подойти.
3. Эвристический подход. Любые идеи, средние по сложности и качеству между двумя предыдущими. Например, те же случайные перемещения клеток, но только в те области, в которых перемещений ещё не было.

Comment: @Sergiks чем же пропорции сторон могут помешать?

Comment: в этом алгоритме форма каждой области стремится к окружности вокруг её центра. Поэтому длинная изогнутая «змейка» маловероятна. Это ближе к паттерну Вороного.

Comment: @Sergiks совсем не обязательно к окружности, это зависит от количества областей и расстояний между ними. А если в этой игре так необходимы изогнутые фигуры, то можно просто ставить каждой области два-три центра по соседству.

Comment: тут поле в довольно «низком разрешении». Расставляя центры случайно можно создать невозможные ситуации, когда, напр. одна область отрезала собой угол, в котором осталось недостатонно клеток для полноценной области.

Comment: Все клетки привязываются сначала к ближайшей области. То есть, никакие элементы не останутся бесхозными (: Так как это явно порождает области неравного размера, здесь вступает в игру алгоритм переноса клеток между смежными областями.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, каким образом здесь можно уровнять площади. Хотя, я подумал, что это может быть и не нужно. Если не найду ничего лучше, использую ваш метод, но было бы интересно увидеть решение исходной задачи.

Comment: @Rennorb добавил несколько идей о выравнивании площадей.

Answer (score 2):

Построение одной области можно сделать так:

1. занять случайную пустую клетку;
2. из соседних 4 клеток выбрать одну случайно, с учётом весов. Вес клетки расчитывается как сумма числа занятых соседей или стен. Пустая клетка посреди поля имеет нулевой вес. Клетка со всеми 4 соседями, или 3 соседями и у стены, или 2 соседями и в углу имеет макс. вес 4. Напр. при наличие двух свободных клеток рядом, у одной вес 1, у другой 4, берётся случайное от 0 до 1, и если оно попадает в диапазон 0 .. 0.2, то выбирается первая клетка, если 0.2 .. 1 – вторая.
3. далее аналогично выбирается новая клетка, только из вариантов всей «колонии», а не только одной последней клетки. Алгоритм тот же.

Демо – [построение одной области](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/2cxbxtbd/9/):

[image: скриншот]

Так строится одна область. Для последующих брать опять случайную точку где угодно, или только на границе уже существующих областей.

**Upd.** Оказалось, просто бросать случайные точки и растить область от каждой – не очень эффективно. Даже если начинать с чертырёх углов, чаще всего остаются «дыры». [Стало лучше](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/2cxbxtbd/14/), когда при наличие среди вариантов глухой дыры с весом 4 (клетка уже закрыта со всех сторон), однозначно выбирается она, без случайностей. Даже **иногда** получаются 100% варианты заполнения:

[image: иногда получается 100% заполнение]

Гарантии от мёртвых зон, отрезанных у стены, нет – есть только вероятностный механизм. Надо внести коррективы. Случайно отбирать только в начале построения области, а чем ближе к концу, тем «строже» следовать макс. весу в ущерб случайности.

Либо добавлять клетки в каждую из областей **по очереди**. Всем по 1-й клетке, затем всем по 2-й, и т.д. до N-й?.. Чувствую, задача сводится к моделированию поведения жидкостей : )

```
"use strict"; // пришлось добавить ради ссылки на jsFiddle
```

Comment: У меня 2 раза из 30-40 получилось 0 cells left empty. То есть гарантий в принципе нет, при 20x20 раз 50 пробовал - ни разу...

Comment: Я ещё не оставил планов улучшить алгоритм! : )  Вернусь к этому позже. Сейчас области строятся по одной, целиком. И нередко создают неразрешимые дырки. Думаю, поможет по очереди, револьвером, раздавать по одной клетке каждой из областей. И надо делать negative lookahead: если после последнего хода образуется новая закрытая с 4 сторон дырка – такой ход делать нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое при маленьком поле нарисовать штук 100 карт или на сколько хватит терпения, поворотами, отражениями получить еще кучу.

При большом поле вариант генерации: реализовать разрезание фигуры по клеточкам на две части в определенном соотношении по площади (1:1, 2:3, 1:2).

1. Выбираем рандомно точку на границе фигуры.
2. В каждой точке сетки мы можем двигаться в нескольких направлениях. Направлений может быть от нуля до трех (ноль - разрез закончен).
3. Выбираем рандомно направление. 
   3.1. Проверяем можем ли резать в данном направлении. Главное, чтобы дойдя до границы получили нужную площадь.
   3.2. Если поле большое, можно резать не по одной клетке, а больше, тоже рандомно.
   3.3. Направление можно попытаться скорректировать, продлив разрез до границы и проверить площадь полученных фигур. Направление, в котором отклонение от необходимой площади минимально, можно выбирать с некоторым большим весом, тогда разрезы будут более ровными. Если веса распределять по-другому могут быть довольно причудливые формы.
4. Разрезав фигуру до конца, получим две фигуры, для каждой из них, если надо повторяем с п.1.

Сложно, но реализуемо...